# How to generate wav file from mysql pdo with into dumpfile

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to generate wav file from mysql blob, but it's not working with PDO. Without PDO it's working good. Can you help me to find mistake? thank you

with PDO not working

```
$q = $CNT->prepare("select recording from music where id = :id INTO DUMPFILE '/music-$filename-$id.wav'");
$q->execute(
array(
':id'=>"$id"
)
);
```

without PDO working good

```
mysql_query("SELECT recording FROM music WHERE id = '".$id."' INTO DUMPFILE '/music-$filename-$id.wav'");
```

Comment: Please expand on _"not working"_. How is it _not working_? Are there any errors generated? FYI, the double-quotes around `"$id"` are unnecessary. You should just have `':id' => $id` though this (probably) won't be the cause of your problem

Answer (score -3):

I found solution. I'm using select without INTO DUMPFILE and then: `file_put_contents("music-$filename-$id.wav", $recording);`

New file from blob has been generated.